# How do I delete all contacts in Google apps permanently?

Tags: gmail, privacy, google-contacts

When you have synced your contacts on your Android phone with Google contacts and decide to withdraw them from Google, how can you permanently delete them?

I went to Gmail->Contacts and there I could delete them all, but when I look into the data I get from the [Google takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) the deleted contacts are all still there.

How can I totally whipe all contacts from Google?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not long ago, that you synced there is an option in your contacts:

> You can restore your contact list to the state that it was in at any point within the past 30 days. This is a great way to recover deleted contacts, undo an import or undo a merge.

I now restored the contacts to the point 30 days ago, see

> Restore contacts: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1069522?hl=en-GB

That was a time, when I had no contacts in my list yet.

Now the loads of contacts, I synced from my phone are gone in the takeout too.

(Though you cannot be sure, google isn't keeping them somewhere else)

***This is not a solution if you used Google contacts for a long time already***

Maybe we find a solution for [How do I obfuscate all contacts in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60877/how-do-i-obfuscate-all-contacts-in-gmail)